# ASP.NET MVC login return URL is repeating on the browser URL

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple login screen in my ASP.NET MVC application. I have an odd experience with it. The return URL on the browser is repeating and looks something like this

```
"http://localhost:65023/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253Dhome%2525252525252525252525252525252525252Findex"
```

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

I have tried below things, added below configuration in my `web.config` file.

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxQueryString="32768"/>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

[Error on browser]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG3O6.png]

Comment: Seems like you have recursive call to `/Account/Login` in your code. Show code of your `Login` method, please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have Authorize attribute in your Login action. When you go to Account/Login, this action directing you to Account/Login again. So, you can try to add AllowAnonymous attribute to your Login action.

Comment: Thanks @Soner Evran able to resolved it adding AllowAnonymous  works!